# SOAP - null body

Tags: java, http, soap

[image]Have a SOAP response that I can't parse into NodeList.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
    <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap- 
                   env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soap-env:Body>
            <s0:response xmlns:s0="urn:company.processing.messages">
                <newOutput>
                    <messageType>OKAY</messageType>
                    <messageCode>00000000</messageCode>
                    <messageText>SUCCESSFUL</messageText>
                </newOutput>
            </s0:response>
        </soap-env:Body> 
    </soap-env:Envelope>
```

Returns NullPointerException:

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = ((SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse()).getSaajMessage();
NodeList nodeList = soapMessage.getSOAPBody().getChildNodes().item(0).getFirstChild().getChildNodes();
```

My guess something is wrong with the the format of this message but can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was with XML formatting. Resolved.